# Table sides by side with input/search on top on first table

Tags: jquery, css, html-table

I have two tables that I would like next to each other. "mytable" needs to be centered on screen with "myinput" centered on top. "mytable1" needs to be just to the right of "mytable" and even with top. I can't manage to get the code correct. I threw some of what I've tried in there with inline-block and float right but then it moves "myinput" to the left.

[image: This is the layout I'm looking to do]

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search by any part of name or speed code" title="Type in a name">
 
    <table id="myTable" align="center" style="display: inline-block;">

 <tr>
 <td>Albert Einstein College of Medicine</td>
 <td>718-904-2444</td>
 <td>123</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>Bronx Lebanon Hospital Center</td>
 <td>718-518-5118</td>
 <td>123</td>
 </tr>
 
 
    </table>

    <table id="myTable1" style="float: right;">
    <tr>
 <td>1</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>2</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>3</td>
 </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<div align="center">
<table id="myTable" align="center" style="display: inline-block;">
<tbody>
<tr style="text-align: center;">
    <td><input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search by any part of name or speed code" title="Type in a name"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Albert Einstein College of Medicine</td>
<td>718-904-2444</td>
<td>123</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Bronx Lebanon Hospital Center</td>
<td>718-518-5118</td>
<td>123</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>

<table id="myTable1" style="display: inline-block;">
<tbody><tr>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>3</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't know what you want exactly But please check this code.

Comment: For some reason when I code it this way my input bar is at the bottom of my table. That might not be your fault though it might be my current CSS with jquery. I might need to post more of my code to get this right.

Comment: I added back an image of what I'm attempting to do.